# Could not transfer artifact com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:pom:4.9.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, okhttp, mockwebserver

I have encountered a problem while importing the `MockWebServer` dependencies into my project

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Idea is showing 2 problems:

- `Dependency 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1' not found`
- `Dependency 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.9.1' not found`

And reload all maven projects results in a big "stacktrace" which generally says that it can't resolve any of the dependencies.

Running maven goal `compile` results in an error:

> Could not transfer artifact com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:pom:4.9.1
> from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer
> failed for
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/4.9.1/okhttp-4.9.1.pom

Thanks.

My repo settings: [image: repo settings screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a network issue... apart from that the url is wrong (correct: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)...

Comment: @khmarbaise actually maybe you're right about the network issue. Today I'm unable to access some websites without a VPN, it just doesn't connect. Invalidating cache didn't do a thing by the way and I still could redownload every other dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. I believe it's my ISP problems. For some reason it doesn't give access to the repo links. Using VPN I was able to download the dependencies